# Filter to create Xerox/Photocopy image from Color images of documents

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filter, computer-vision, xerox

I have color images of Documents. Sample Input

[image: PAN card]
(taken from https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/pan-card-21687536812.html)

I wish to create realistic xerox/photocopy image from this. Most xerox/photocopy are set on low tone.
Here is a sample output (sample output is not xerox of sample input - I couldnt find the same image for both on net)
[image] (taken from http://shrikantmail7862.blogspot.com/2016/06/)

Note output is not a simple Black and White of the color image.

I am looking for a tools/code/algos that will do this for me. I need to do this for over 0.1M images
I am sure there must be such a filter in image processing. Looking for suitable pointers

Comment: Convert to grayscale, increase the contrast to remove details, then decrease contrast to simulate poor ink. Alternatively, you can convert to grayscale, then turn to back & white with dithering.

Comment: One tool that adds noise, rotates, reduces color, etc. is here: https://supertool.org/make-a-pdf-look-printed-and-scanned/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a xerox like effect, an approach would be to convert the image to greyscale and then reduce the color space.

```py
def xeroxFilter(imgPath, colorSpaceReduction=8, rotate=False, fillColor=(255,255,255)):
  '''Takes image as input and returns a xerox like image of the input image.
  impPath: Name of Image(keep the images in the same folder as this script)
  colorSpaceReduction:  Reducing the color space. Higher the value, Higher the reduction. 
  rotate: Rotate to the image
  fillColor: Specify the RGB value of the background color after roatation
  '''
  print("Original Image")
  cv2_imshow(cv2.imread(imgPath))

  print('GreyScale')
  cv2_imshow(cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
  
  print('Color Space Reduced')
  color_reduced_img = cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) // colorSpaceReduction * colorSpaceReduction + colorSpaceReduction // 2
  cv2_imshow(color_reduced_img)
  file_name = 'ColorSpaceReduced-'+imgPath.split('.')[0]+'.png'
  cv2.imwrite(file_name, color_reduced_img)
  
  if rotate:
    print("Rotated")
    img = Image.open(file_name)
    rgb_img = Image.new("RGBA", img.size)
    rgb_img.paste(img)
    rotated_img = rgb_img.rotate(random.randint(-25,25), expand = 1, fillcolor = fillColor)
    display(rotated_img)
    rotated_img.save('Rotated-'+file_name)
  print("Original Image")
  cv2_imshow(cv2.imread(imgPath))

xeroxFilter('MCRV7.jpg', rotate=True)
```

Color Space Reduction code (credits [@elizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1579030/eliezer-bernart))
The output when the first image is passed into the script can be found below:
[[image: Xerox Filter Output Imge][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45qJf.png)

Answer (score 0):

'''Takes image as output and returns a original like image of the output image.
impPath: Name of Image(keep the images in the same folder as this script)
colorSpaceReduction:  Reducing the color space. Higher the value, Higher the reduction.
rotate: Rotate to the image
fillColor: Specify the RGB value of the background color after roatation

```
print("Original Image")
cv2_imshow(cv2.imread(imgPath))

print('GreyScale')
cv2_imshow(cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
  
print('Color Space Reduced')
```